# cannot log into mysql locally

Tags: mysql, fedora

When I try to log into mysql locally using the command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I can access the server remotely(not as root) and my web pages are using the mysql fine, but locally I cannot log on(which I need because I need to create some users).  Only change I made was to attach another drive to the server and move the sql data there.  Here's my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/media/ephemeral0/data/mysql
socket=/media/ephemeral0/data/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# adding more config
skip-external-locking
long_query_time=1
slow_query_log
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/log-slow-queries.log
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id= 1

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
myisam_recover_options
```

I read I need to edit the socket info in my.cnf to make sure it points to the right socket file..I double checked and the file exists(although it starts with an S when I do ls -l "srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql          0 Jun 21 03:43 mysql.sock").

I'm not really sure how to resolve this.  I have tried to reboot and ran yum update to make sure I was running the latest packages.

Please help!

Comment: try: `socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: Thanks john it worked.  okay I just realized you got that path from the error(sorry not sure why I didn't get that either) but is there a reason its picking that location instead of the one I specified? also can you put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: did you make sure you restarted MySQL after changing your `my.cnf`?

Comment: yes i did..I restarted the entire server as well..it didn't work, it was still using the path above instead of the one in my.cnf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the `[mysqld]` section of your `my.cnf` you have set the socket to a non-standard location of `/media/ephemeral0/data/mysql/mysql.sock` but the `[mysqld]` section only affects the server and not the client.

You should put that option in the `[mysql]` section instead - then it will apply to both the client and the server.

You can find more information on option files and the sections in them in the mysql documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html

Comment: Thank you, that worked and I understand the problem now.  I didn't know all the options, when I changed the file, I just read the old settings and swapped them with the new ones.  Thanks alot.